# Change Illustrator's save method to not have -01 extension?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, save

Wondering if there is a way to change the way Illustrator outputs png and jpegs with the -01, -02, -03, etc. extensions. Is there a way to tell it not to do this? I use Illustrator for web design and would like to not have the extension on it.

Comment: At least for PNG files, the 01 suffix is in reference to the artboards, so by naming artboards there is a bit of a workaround.

Answer (score 6):

When saving, Illustrator uses the name of your document.  If you create "Untitled-1", "Untitled-2", "Untitled-3", then those are the names it will use when saving.

When you create a new document, specify a name (it's at the top of the New Document dialog, above artboard/document settings).  Illustrator will then use this name for files it generates.

**Edit**

If you're talking about the "_##" suffix attached to slices, you must set the slice options.  To do so, use the Slice Select Tool to select the slice, then go to `Object` ⇒ `Slice` ⇒ `Slice Options` and name it something else.

Either from within Illustrator, or within your filesystem, at some point *you* have to tell the program what you want the images to be called...